# Trigger mouseout event

Tags: javascript

I have an element with an `element.addEventListener('mouseout')`, and I would like to trigger it using Vanilla JavaScript (nothing with jQuery). How could I do this?

I cannot change it to `element.onmouseout = function() {}`. I cannot do `element.dispatchEvent(new Event('mouseout'))` due to `new Event()` not being a trusted event.

Comment: It is not possible to programmaticly set a trusted event according to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted)

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your `Event` to a `MouseEvent`

```js
document.getElementById('element').addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
  console.log('triggered mouseout');
});

const newEvent = new MouseEvent('mouseout');
document.getElementById("element").dispatchEvent(newEvent);
```

See here for a [live version](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-saha-vh1svk?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: `new MouseEvent('mouseout')` wouldn't be a trusted event, and I check if every event is trusted.